# Add style to echo

Tags: php, css

I want to add a float right style to this php echo

```
<?php echo $PAGE->button; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You can't really add style to an echo. It's an operator. It can be used to output HTML, which CAN be styled with CSS or legacy HTML attributes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
    <?php echo $PAGE->button; ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

And in CSS:

```
.foo {
    /* some styles here */
}
```

Or just simply, but not recommended inline styling:

```
<?php echo "<div style='float: right;'>". $PAGE->button ."</div>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo "<div style=\"float:right;\">" . $PAGE->button . "</div>"; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

This will float the entire button to the right

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo "<div style='float: right;'>". $PAGE->button ."</div>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not give style to echo function. but you can wrap it in lable or p or any other html tag and give float: right in style.

like this,

```
<p style="float: right;"><?php echo $PAGE->button.?></p>
```

Comment: Is echo actually a function? I think it works more like an operator.

Comment: nopr it is php function as far as i know.

Comment: Well, the official docs disagree with you: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: What that means is echo can be used like: `echo '';` or `echo ('');` or `echo '','','',''` or `echo ''.''.''.''`

Answer (score 0):

Doing it in a cleaner way:

```
<div style="float: right;"><?php echo $PAGE->button; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options, the preferred method is to define the values for your button within a CSS file:

- This keeps overhead down as your not loading more bytes on each page load as you can setup your server to cache stylesheets.

Or a stylesheet within your head:

- This will not save you bandwidth but will keep styling separated from
  html and keep style's in on place.

Or you can use inline styling.

```
<style>
.button{
    float:right;
}
</style>

<!--Using the button class from the stylesheet, Notice how many less characters there is-->
<input type="button" value="Button" class="button" name="B3">
<br /> 

<!--Using the same class from the stylesheet, but wrapping the button within a span-->
<span class="button"><input type="button" value="Button" name="B3"></span>
<br /> 

<!--The inline method-->
<span style="float:right"><input type="button" value="Button" name="B3"></span>
```