# CSS Style in <php echo>?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to add CSS style

```
right: 10px
top: 10px
```

To this:

```
<?php echo DISPLAY_ULTIMATE_PLUS(); ?>
```

How do I connect these two? And where to I put the:

```
<?php echo DISPLAY_ULTIMATE_PLUS(); ?>
```

??

Because it's Wordpress and it says "Place the code in your theme codes"

Thanks

Comment: Place `<?php echo DISPLAY_ULTIMATE_PLUS(); ?>` in your theme files and then add the CSS to any class it generates ? Need more details to help you.

Comment: We definitely need more information to help with this

Comment: Asking two very different questions here, you'd be better off asking the wordpress question separately, plus this is a duplicate... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850608/add-style-to-echo

Comment: You'd better find DISPLAY_ULTIMATE_PLUS() and check what it does, if it echoes html look in the function and add css there...

Comment: Okey so I have a wordpress site and this is because I want to place my social buttons on a specific place on my site, and I have to place these php echo tag in "theme codes" and change from there?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to place the code at the appropriate place within your theme file.

Since you want to apply some styles to it, you could wrap it in a div with a class assigned to it.

```
<div class="social_buttons">
  <?php echo DISPLAY_ULTIMATE_PLUS(); ?>
</div>
```

Then add the CSS to your stylesheet, *usually* found in the theme folder and named "style.css".

```
.social_buttons{
  right: 10px
  top: 10px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use this

```
<style>
.notificacion {
  background: red;
   border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}
</style>

<?php 
$a=3; 
echo '<div class="notificacion">', $a,'</div>';?>
```

Tell me if works :D